# How to add a user defined control to a form in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

Hi: I have created a very simple user defined control (a container) with the visual IDE of Visual Foxpro 9 and stored it into a VCX file (sisweb.vcx)

After that I've created (visually) a form and in the INIT event I've tried to instantiate the previous container control and add to the form:

```
oContainer=newobject("xContainer","sisweb.vcx")
ThisForm.AddObject("Contx","oContainer")
ThisForm.Contx.Width=230
```

Unfortunatelly, when trying to ADD the container object, it rises an error saying that oContainer doesn't exists.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to add an object dynamically at run-time, you could do something like

```
Thisform.NewObject("Contx", "xContainer", "sisweb.vcx")
Thisform.Contx.Width = 230
Thisform.Contx.Visible = .T.
```

Where assigning the `Visible` property explicitly is important.

On the other hand, you could also add it "visually" in the Designer by dragging it from the Project Manager's "Classes" tab, or by using the bookshelf icon of the Form / Class Designer's "Controls" toolbar, or the "Toolbox" in the "Tools" menu

Comment: It may be worth stating what Alberto did wrong -- specifically, that VFP does not allow an existing instance to be added to a container.  (In fact, I'm not sure very many UI designers allow that, due to the potential headaches.)